# How to add jQuery UI to an Asset Bundle

Tags: php, jquery-ui, yii2, assetbundle

I have the following asset bundle and i would like to add jQuery UI as part of it as well. How can I do it?

```
<?php
namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AdminAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot/assets-admin';
    public $baseUrl = '@web/assets-admin';

    public $css = [
        'css/common.css',
        'css/animations.css',
        'css/editor.css',
        'css/form.css',
        'css/fileupload.css',
        'css/template.css',
        'css/icons.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/libs/modernizr.js',
        'js/script.js'
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

At first install official [JUI Extension for Yii 2](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-jui).

Then add `yii\jui\JuiAsset` to list of dependent assets:

```
public $depends = [
    'yii\jui\JuiAsset',
    ...       
];
```

`yii\web\JqueryAsset` in this case is not required because `JuiAsset` already has it in dependencies list so it will be included as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since the accepted answer no longer works in Yii 2.10 , I will add my solution.

It is necessary now to include the CoreAsset, plus the desired jui components. The other components depend on CoreAsset so for example if you want to use draggable, do:

```
public $depends = [
    //'yii\jui\CoreAsset', // included as dependency of draggable
    'yii\jui\DraggableAsset',
];
```